# Passing values into a external function JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to create external general function for all my document. That function I want to use "this" method to work inside process of function and that "this" value come from difference buttons. But this code is not working for me. how to solve it out.

**jQuery Code:**

```
function myFunction(e){ 
    var inp = $(this).val(), target = e.target, position = target.selectionStart;
    inp = inp.replace(/a/g, "A");
    inp = inp.replace(/i/g, "I");
    inp = inp.replace(/u/g, "U");
    inp = inp.replace(/e/g, "E");
    $(this).val(inp);
    $(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(position, position );
}
```

Send the value to external function using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Search').keyup(myFunction('#Search'));
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<form name="inputform">
    <input class="Search" type="text" autofocus name="searchbox"  id="Search" style="width:800px; height:200px;">
</form>
```

If I put directly text box id it is working fine.

Comment: why are you passing `'#Search'` to `myFunction('#Search')` when binding it to keyup? do you need to pass in some config?

Comment: No. this external function is general. therefor I am using some more text box. so If I change to anther text box, want to pass ID of that text box to process in side of function. That why I used also "this" as a general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass `#Search` as argument of `myFunction` like `myFunction('#Search')`. You can do it simply like following.

```
$('#Search').keyup(myFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is a call back; jQuery passes the event information to your call back.

so when you do: `$('#Search').keyup(myFunction('#Search'));`

What's happening is `(myFunction()('#Search'))(e)` which isn't what you want. The `e` is the event information from the `key up` event listener that jQuery passes.

If you want to pass in '#Search' you can create a function that throws away this `e` and passes what you want inside, like this.

```
$('#Search').keyup(function(e){
    myFunction('#Search');
});
```

But your function isn't listening for a string, its listening for the event information so you can do

```
$('#Search').keyup(myFuction)
```

Comment: But $('#Search').keyup(function(){myFunction('#Search'); }); this also not working.

Comment: It says right there: `$('#Search').keyup(myFuction)`